# JavaScript and OnClick Events, making classes hidden

Tags: javascript, class, onclick, hidden, visible

I am trying to make a "calculator" as practice as I am learning Javascript. Basically, the user makes a password.  After the password is made the user needs to enter the password again.  If the passwords match, then a calculator will appear and the password box will disappear.  The code works up until re entering the password, I can not get past this part and am stumped!  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pwd = prompt("Please enter your FAB password here", "");

            function DisplayCalc(pwd2) {
                var NewPwd = document.getElementById(pwd2);

                if (Newpwd == pwd) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName(NotVisibleClass).style.visibility = 'visible';
                    document.getElementsByClassName(VisibleClass).style.visibility = 'hidden';

                }
                else {
                    alert("Wrong Password Twinkle Toes!!");
                }
            }


        </script>
        <style>
            /* Need to style title to have a different color for every letter*/
            .Red{
                color: #f00;
            }
            .Orange{
                color: orange;
            }
            .Yellow{
                color: yellow;
            }
            .Green{
                color: green;
            }
            .Blue{
                color: blue;
            }
            .Purple{
                color: purple;
            }
            /*Need to have the background change colors*/
            .ResDivBy7{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .ResDivBy6{
                background-color: orange;
            }
            .ResDivBy5{
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .ResDivBy4{
                background-color: green;
            }
            .ResDivBy3{
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .ResDivBy2{
                background-color: purple;
            }
            /*Need to hide elements */
            .NotVisibleClass{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            /*Need to show elements*/
            .VisibleClass{
                visibility: visible;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Secret Rainbow Calculator!!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>
                <span class="Red">S</span><span class="Orange">E</span><span class="Yellow">C</span><span class="Green">R</span><span class="Blue">E</span><span class="Purple">T</span>
                <span class="Red">R</span><span class="Orange">A</span><span class="Yellow">I</span><span class="Green">N</span><span class="Blue">B</span><span class="Purple">O</span><span class="Red">W</span>
                <span class="Orange">C</span><span class="Yellow">A</span><span class="Green">L</span><span class="Blue">C</span><span class="Purple">U</span><span class="Red">L</span><span class="Orange">A</span><span class="Yellow">T</span><span class="Green">O</span><span class="Blue">R</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="VisibleClass">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Please Enter Your FABULOUS Password!</label>
                    <input type="password"
                           id="pwd2" />
                    <button type="button" onClick= DisplayCalc(pwd2)>
                            Click Me When Done!</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="NotVisibleClass">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="calcScreen" readonly="readonly"/>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> 1 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 2 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 3 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 4 </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> 5 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 6 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 7 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 8 </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> Enter </button>
                    <button type="button"> 0 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 9 </button>
                    <button type="button"> Clear </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> + </button>
                    <button type="button"> - </button>
                    <button type="button"> * </button>
                    <button type="button"> / </button>    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting the _Node_ and not it's `.value`. I also can't see where the variable `pwd2` is set, are you sure you didn't mean to use a _String literal_?

Answer (score 1):

My console says that 'Newpwd' is not defined when comparing (Newpwd == pwd). Looking at your source, you need to capitalize the 'P' in 'Newpwd.'

Answer (score 0):

As Justin H mentioned, the 'P' in your variable 'NewPwd' that's being used in your `if` statement has a lowercase P. JavaScript is a case sensitive language and there fore `Newpwd` is undefined. Capitalize the P in your if statement and you should be back up and running. In addition, you're just getting the document element by ID which will not return it's value. It will return an object. So, you also need to modify the defnition of the your variable `NewPwd`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pwd = prompt("Please enter your FAB password here", "");

            function DisplayCalc(pwd2) {
             //Variable NewPwd with capital 'P'
                var NewPwd = document.getElementById(pwd2).value;
              //Use of Variable NewPwd used without capitalization of 'P'
                if (Newpwd == pwd) { //Newpwd == pwd returns undefined
                    document.getElementsByClassName(NotVisibleClass).style.visibility = 'visible';
                    document.getElementsByClassName(VisibleClass).style.visibility = 'hidden';

                }
                else {
                    alert("Wrong Password Twinkle Toes!!");
                }
            }


        </script>
        <style>
            /* Need to style title to have a different color for every letter*/
            .Red{
                color: #f00;
            }
            .Orange{
                color: orange;
            }
            .Yellow{
                color: yellow;
            }
            .Green{
                color: green;
            }
            .Blue{
                color: blue;
            }
            .Purple{
                color: purple;
            }
            /*Need to have the background change colors*/
            .ResDivBy7{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .ResDivBy6{
                background-color: orange;
            }
            .ResDivBy5{
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .ResDivBy4{
                background-color: green;
            }
            .ResDivBy3{
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .ResDivBy2{
                background-color: purple;
            }
            /*Need to hide elements */
            .NotVisibleClass{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            /*Need to show elements*/
            .VisibleClass{
                visibility: visible;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Secret Rainbow Calculator!!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>
                <span class="Red">S</span><span class="Orange">E</span><span class="Yellow">C</span><span class="Green">R</span><span class="Blue">E</span><span class="Purple">T</span>
                <span class="Red">R</span><span class="Orange">A</span><span class="Yellow">I</span><span class="Green">N</span><span class="Blue">B</span><span class="Purple">O</span><span class="Red">W</span>
                <span class="Orange">C</span><span class="Yellow">A</span><span class="Green">L</span><span class="Blue">C</span><span class="Purple">U</span><span class="Red">L</span><span class="Orange">A</span><span class="Yellow">T</span><span class="Green">O</span><span class="Blue">R</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="VisibleClass">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Please Enter Your FABULOUS Password!</label>
                    <input type="password"
                           id="pwd2" />
                    <button type="button" onClick= DisplayCalc(pwd2)>
                            Click Me When Done!</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="NotVisibleClass">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="calcScreen" readonly="readonly"/>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> 1 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 2 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 3 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 4 </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> 5 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 6 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 7 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 8 </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> Enter </button>
                    <button type="button"> 0 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 9 </button>
                    <button type="button"> Clear </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> + </button>
                    <button type="button"> - </button>
                    <button type="button"> * </button>
                    <button type="button"> / </button>    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pwd = prompt("Please enter your FAB password here", "");

            function DisplayCalc(pwd2) {
                var NewPwd = document.getElementById(pwd2).value;

                if (NewPwd == pwd) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('NotVisibleClass')[0].style.visibility  = 'visible';
                    document.getElementsByClassName('VisibleClass')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';

                }
                else {
                    alert("Wrong Password Twinkle Toes!!");
                }
            }


        </script>
        <style>
            /* Need to style title to have a different color for every letter*/
            .Red{
                color: #f00;
            }
            .Orange{
                color: orange;
            }
            .Yellow{
                color: yellow;
            }
            .Green{
                color: green;
            }
            .Blue{
                color: blue;
            }
            .Purple{
                color: purple;
            }
            /*Need to have the background change colors*/
            .ResDivBy7{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .ResDivBy6{
                background-color: orange;
            }
            .ResDivBy5{
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .ResDivBy4{
                background-color: green;
            }
            .ResDivBy3{
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .ResDivBy2{
                background-color: purple;
            }
            /*Need to hide elements */
            .NotVisibleClass{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            /*Need to show elements*/
            .VisibleClass{
                visibility: visible;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Secret Rainbow Calculator!!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>
                <span class="Red">S</span><span class="Orange">E</span><span class="Yellow">C</span><span class="Green">R</span><span class="Blue">E</span><span class="Purple">T</span>
                <span class="Red">R</span><span class="Orange">A</span><span class="Yellow">I</span><span class="Green">N</span><span class="Blue">B</span><span class="Purple">O</span><span class="Red">W</span>
                <span class="Orange">C</span><span class="Yellow">A</span><span class="Green">L</span><span class="Blue">C</span><span class="Purple">U</span><span class="Red">L</span><span class="Orange">A</span><span class="Yellow">T</span><span class="Green">O</span><span class="Blue">R</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="VisibleClass">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Please Enter Your FABULOUS Password!</label>
                    <input type="password"
                           id="pwd2" />
                    <button type="button" onClick="DisplayCalc('pwd2')">
                            Click Me When Done!</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="NotVisibleClass">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="calcScreen" readonly="readonly"/>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> 1 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 2 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 3 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 4 </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> 5 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 6 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 7 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 8 </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> Enter </button>
                    <button type="button"> 0 </button>
                    <button type="button"> 9 </button>
                    <button type="button"> Clear </button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button"> + </button>
                    <button type="button"> - </button>
                    <button type="button"> * </button>
                    <button type="button"> / </button>    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct the var NewPwd, correct the onClick syntax, usage of getByClassName. Most of the places you were using string params as if it was a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the follwoing section :

```
 if (Newpwd == pwd) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName(NotVisibleClass).style.visibility = 'visible';
                    document.getElementsByClassName(VisibleClass).style.visibility = 'hidden';

                }
```

change `'Newpwd == pwd'` to `'NewPwd.value == pwd'`

Your code will still need some css related changes.

I would suggest you start using some developer tools (like the Chrome Browser's developer tools.

Simply press F12 on the desired page, in Google Chrome, to open the Developer Tools page, and explore you code.)